# Searching Values in Mysql Db by passing multiple values of same parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate a report of certain criteria from my website, The website is an an web application used to save breakdown time and details of the machines in a company. Here i want to generate an report based on breakdown type, breakdown machine , break down attended by etc.,.

So i have created an search form to do so and i have used dynamic dropdown menu from my database and successfully created a code that will select multiple values as well like (Under Machine- we can select machine names like machine1,machine2 and so on) and after i press search it shows only the result for the last selected value but i want to show the results(details) of all the selected values.

```
**form.php**

<?php
//index.php
include('database_connection.php');
$country = '';
$query = "
SELECT type FROM reporttype
";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row)
{
$country .= '<option value="'.$row["type"].'">'.$row["type"].'</option>';
}
?>
<div class="container">
<h2 align="center"></h2><br /><br />
<form method="post" id="insert_data" action="insert.php">
<label class="col-md-2 bdlabel">Break Down</label>
<select name="country" id="country" class="col-md-10 form-control action">
<option value="">Choose a Category</option>
<?php echo $country; ?>
</select>
<br />
<select name="city" id="city" multiple class="form-control">
</select>
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_city" id="hidden_city" />
<div class="form-group">
<div class="datepic">
<label class="col-md-2 bdlabel bdfrom">From</label>
<input type="date" name="bdfrom" class="col-md-4">
</div>
<div class="datepic1">
<label class="col-md-2 bdlabel bdto">To</label>
<input type="date" name="bdto" class="col-md-4">
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="search" id="action" class="btn btn-info" 
value="Search" />
</form>
</div>
<script>
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#city').lwMultiSelect();
$('.action').change(function(){
if($(this).val() != '')
{
var action = $(this).attr("id");
var query = $(this).val();
var result = '';
if(action == 'country')
{
result = 'city';
}
$.ajax({
url:'fetch.php',
method:"POST",
data:{action:action, query:query},
success:function(data)
{
$('#'+result).html(data);
if(result == 'city')
{
$('#city').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').updateList();
}
}
})
}
});
});
</script>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
//insert.php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['search']))
$city=$_POST['city'];
$from=$_POST['bdfrom'];
$to=$_GET['bdto'];
{
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM breakdownentry
WHERE bdmwc in ('$city') || bdmname in ('$city') || bdaname in ('$city') ") 
or die(mysql_error());         
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following         
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){             
echo "<p>".$results['bdmwc']."</p>";
}
}
else{ 
echo "No results";
}
}
?>
```

[Actual Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9ox6.png)

[Output I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1QPr.png)

[Db table value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIXfS.png)

```
What i want to show is wire drawing and nail but only nail value is been shown.
```

Comment: Has your tab key broken?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's pretty unreadable as it is.

Comment: After reformatting your code `echo $city` and show us what is in that variable

Comment: Then put your query in a variable like `$sql` and echo that and see what is being sent to the database for execution

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly yeah i was new to php and stackoverflow too, when i copy pasted my code it showed indend error and asked to leave four whitespaces before every line of code ... sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer , i have to use implode function to get the multiple values through array. After using implode function in the search query i was able to get the multiple values and got my desired results. By the by thanks @RiggsFolly and @OlgertElezi for your help ,the square braces in select tag helped to pass an array value .

I have attached my working code with this . Again Thanks evryone

```
<?php
                                    //insert.php
                                        include('db.php');
                                        if(isset($_POST['search'])) 
                                            $category=($_POST["country"]);                                  
                                            $machine=($_POST["city"]);
                                            $from=($_POST["bdfrom"]);
                                            $to=($_POST["bdto"]);

                                                $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM breakdownentry WHERE ((bddate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')) && (bdmname IN ('".implode("','",$machine)."') || bdmwc IN ('".implode("','",$machine)."') || bdaname IN ('".implode("','",$machine)."')) ") or die(mysql_error());

                                                if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="widget-content2 resulttable">
                                        <label class="tableheadtb"><?php echo $category.' Break Down details';?></label>
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table class="table table-bordered ">
                                                <?php

                                                    // if one or more rows are returned do following
                                                    $limit = 10;  
                                                    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
                                                        $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  

                                                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM breakdownentry LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
                                                        $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);    
                                                        $a=$start_from + 0;
                                                        $efslno=$start_from + 1354;

                                                ?>

                                                 <thead>
                                                        <tr style="background-color:#FDFE90">
                                                        <th><strong>S.No</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>Complaint-Date</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>B/D S.No</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>Machine ID</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>Machine Name</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>Work Centre</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>B/D ID</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>Attended by(ID)</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>Attended by Name</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>B/D Type</strong></th>                                                  
                                                        <th><strong>B/D Time (Hours)</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>B/D Time (Minutes)</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>B/D Time (Total)</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>B/D Details</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>Work Done</strong></th>
                                                        <th><strong>Complaint Status</strong></th>                  
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>

                                                <?php   
                                                    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){ 

                                                ?>                                                                                              
                                                <tbody>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><?php echo ++$a;?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bddate'];?></td>
                                                        <td><?php 
                                                                $slno = ++$efslno;
                                                                echo $slno;?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdmid'];?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdmname'];?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdmwc'];?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdbdid'];?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdtid'];?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdtname'];?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdbdname'];?></td>                                                         
                                                        <td><?php 
                                                                $bdbreakoccur1=$results['bdbreakreport'];
                                                                $bdamotime1=$results['bdamotime'];
                                                                $time=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT (HOUR (TIMEDIFF ('$bdamotime1','$bdbreakoccur1')))"));                                                              
                                                                echo $time[0] ;
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td><?php 
                                                                $bdbreakoccur1=$results['bdbreakreport'];
                                                                $bdamotime1=$results['bdamotime'];
                                                                $time=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT (MINUTE (TIMEDIFF ('$bdamotime1','$bdbreakoccur1')))"));                                                                
                                                                echo $time[0] ;
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td><?php 
                                                                $bdbreakoccur1=$results['bdbreakreport'];
                                                                $bdamotime1=$results['bdamotime'];
                                                                $time=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT ((HOUR (TIMEDIFF ('$bdamotime1','$bdbreakoccur1'))*(60)) + (MINUTE (TIMEDIFF('$bdamotime1','$bdbreakoccur1'))))/60"));
                                                                echo $time[0] ;
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdacause'];?></td>                                                         
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdawdc'];?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $results['bdaradio'];?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                                <?php           
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php  
                                            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM breakdownentry";  
                                            $rs_result = mysql_query($sql);  
                                            $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);  
                                            $total_records = $row[0];  
                                            $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
                                            $pagLink = "<div class='widget-foot'>";  
                                            for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
                                                $pagLink .= "<a href='break-down-list.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
                                                };  
                                            echo $pagLink . "</div>";
                                            }
                                            else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
                                                    echo "<p class='ep'>No Results to Show</p>";
                                            }  
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get multiple values on the form you should add `[]` at the end of the `name` attribute

For your examples:

```
<select name="city[]" id="city" multiple class="form-control">
```

Comment: **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. So an example of the code to change would be a good idea

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: bdto in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmms\insert.php on line 7

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmms\insert.php on line 13

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmms\insert.php on line 13

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmms\insert.php on line 13
No results

Comment: Yes because you use post as requested method, just change $_GET['bdto'] to this $_POST['bdto'] on line 7 insert.php